# ArrayList Syntax

Tags: c#, arraylist

So I need to use an ArrayList in C#. I looked it up in MSDN and they said I had to create a class, add System.Collections and Add

```
IList, ICollection, IEnumerable,
```

`ICloneable` to the class

```
class clsExample : IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, ICloneable;
```

then I tried to use my Arraylist. So I typed:

```
ArrayList myAL = new ArrayList();
```

But the problem is that when I try to add things to the array (`myAL.Add(1, Example);`) the code doesn't find the `array (myAL)` and underlines an error to it. Am I missing something? 
Code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{
    [SerializableAttribute]

    class clsAL : IList, ICollection, IEnumerable,
    ICloneable
    {
        ArrayList AL = new ArrayList();

    }
}
```

Comment: "Am I missing something? " - Yes, a short representative code snippet that displays your problem.

Comment: *What* code "doesn't find the array"? You're declaring it local to the `clsAL` class here, so external code wouldn't see this private member.

Comment: > `So I need to use an ArrayList in C#` ... and there was the first mistake. ArrayLists in C# are not good. Use a List<T> instead.

Answer (score 2):

`To use ArrayList you do not need to implement the Interfaces` you are having. Remove them and add the object in ArrayList in some method as given below. If it is possible you should look into [**generic list**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) that saves you from type casting.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{     
    class clsAL
    {
        ArrayList AL = new ArrayList();
        public void YourFun()
        {
             AL.Add("First");
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: You can look this [**msdn example**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) for understand how to use ArrayList

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
public class SamplesArrayList  {

   public static void Main()  {

      // Creates and initializes a new ArrayList.
      ArrayList myAL = new ArrayList();
      myAL.Add("Hello");
      myAL.Add("World");
      myAL.Add("!");

      // Displays the properties and values of the ArrayList.
      Console.WriteLine( "myAL" );
      Console.WriteLine( "    Count:    {0}", myAL.Count );
      Console.WriteLine( "    Capacity: {0}", myAL.Capacity );
      Console.Write( "    Values:" );
      PrintValues( myAL );
   }

   public static void PrintValues( IEnumerable myList )  {
      foreach ( Object obj in myList )
         Console.Write( "   {0}", obj );
      Console.WriteLine();
   }

}
```

Comment: it doesn't matter because whenever I type "myAL" it underlines an error to it.

Comment: Well obviously `myAL` is not declared here. Either use the `AL` you declared or rename `AL` to `myAL`.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're forced to use ArrayList for some peculiar reason, I strongly advise using the generic List class instead.

Comment: to be honest I'm taking programming classes and the teacher is teaching us to make Arraylist Classes... it's pretty embarrassing to have to ask other people about this.

Answer (score 0):

For one [`ArrayList.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.add%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) does not have a signature that matches what you are trying to add, it is just an object. The closest thing I can think of is to use the [`ArrayList.Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.insert%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Method like this. The other thing is to make sure that your ArrayList is in Scope where you are trying to use it.

```
AL.Insert(AL.Count,"Example");
```

or

```
Al.Add("Example"); // will append it to the ArrayList
```